# EF Core, ignore model fields inherited from base class

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-core

I am using two Databases in my app - MySQL with EF Core and Realm, as both of them use the same models and to avoid confusion I am using the same model classes for both of them:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Realms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using Realms.Schema;

namespace Data.Models
{
    [Table("entry")]
    public class Entry : RealmObject
    {
        public class EntryType
        {
            public const byte Word = 1;
            public const byte Phrase = 2;
            public const byte Text = 3;
        };

        [Key]
        [PrimaryKey]
        [Column("entry_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("source_id")]
        public int SourceId { get; set; }

        [Indexed]
        [Column("type")]
        public byte Type { get; set; }

        [Column("rate")]
        public int Rate { get; set; }

        [Column("created_at")]
        public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column("updated_at")]
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Phrase Phrase { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Word Word { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Text Text { get; set; }

        public IList<Translation> Translations { get; }

    }
}
```

For EF Core:

```
namespace Data.Contexts
{
    public class EntryContext : BaseContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It works fine but when using with EF Core I get unnecessary fields derived from RealmObject, which is a problem as I am trying to build an API and I don't want anything not defined by me explicitly

```
/ https://localhost:44349/entry/randoms

[
  {
    "id": 34101,
    "userId": 1,
    "sourceId": 1,
    "type": 2,
    "rate": -1,
    "createdAt": "1/26/2020 9:45:07 AM",
    "updatedAt": "4/30/2020 7:18:05 PM",
    "phrase": null,
    "word": null,
    "text": null,
    "translations": [],
    "content": null,
    "isManaged": false,
    "isValid": true,
    "realm": null,
    "objectSchema": null,
    "backlinksCount": 0
  },
]
```

I want to tell EF Core to ignore these inherited fields without breaking anything for Realm:

```
"isManaged": false,
"isValid": true,
"realm": null,
"objectSchema": null,
"backlinksCount": 0
```

How can I do that? Or maybe there is a better way to use one model for two ORMs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fluent API for that

```
namespace Data.Contexts
{
    public class EntryContext : BaseContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
                .Ignore(e => e.IsManaged)
                .Ignore(e => e.IsValid)
                 //etc.
        }
    }
}
```